# Run gcloud commands from PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

We can run shell commands from PHP using shell_exec() command.
When i try to run

```
shell_exec('ls')
```

it gives the list of files and folders.

I want to use shell_exec to get list of instances in the Google Cloud.

I am using

```
shell_exec('gcloud compute instances list')
```

it does not produce any result. When i run the same command 'gcloud compute instances list' on terminal, it shows all the instances under the project.

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Try using "exec" and adding "2>&1" to the end of your command to see what error is being thrown. 

My guess would be it's a authentication problem using gcloud from the command line.

Comment: it does not give any error. when i try the same command from command line it is working fine. When i try to run the same command from a PHP file it shows a blank page (No error).

Comment: When I run the command line tool using php, I get 

Permission errors - gcloud wants to write a .config folder in my webroot. "Fixed" setting permissions more broadly.
Authentication failure - gcloud needs to be logged in using gcloud auth login which can't easily be done from headless call on server side. 

I agree with Jeffrey Rennie, that you're better off using REST API.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using the REST API directly.  Gcloud calls the same API.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list

Google provides a PHP client library that wraps the REST API:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_php_client_library

Comment: Thank you jeffrey for the help. i was able to list the instances using the PHP client library :)